# SvelteKit adapter-static: Support incremental build enabling generating only a specific page instead of entire site

Tags: sveltekit, static-site-generation

We have some medium website (> pages) and would like to prerender the entire site. Upon content changes in some external system, we would like to update only the specific page which contains the updated content and deploy the updated version of the page as static html page to some publishing service (webserver, CDN, Netlify, etc.).

I have seen that SvelteKit supports this SSG rendering approach through the [adapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static) but as far as I've seen it always builds all the pages/routes for every build. This is currently a blocker because if an editor updates some content it takes more than 15 minutes (rough estimate if you have around 1500 pages) to see this update online.

Is there already some possibility to simply build some specific page or route?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that this is still an open feature request and to be discussed there: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2369